# Online advertisement performance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I want to find a mathematically-based way to decide wether or not to pause a keyword belonging to an online advertisement campaign.

A keyword might make a user click my ad which might lead to a sale. If, during the last 90 days, a keyword didn't generate any sale, I have to consider pausing it. In that case, I use the average performance of the campaign to make the decision:

$P=\frac{N_{sales}}{N_{clicks}}$

Then, the question is: has the keyword performed far from the campaign (on average) because it's a bad choice (and should be paused) or because it's not been given enough time (not enough clicks, in consequence)?

The method I thought of is as follows:
Do a Chi-Squared test with some significance level (e.g. 5%) and find the needed number of clicks.

$90$ $days \rightarrow 89$ $DOF$

$\chi^2_{critical} = 112.022$ ($@p=0.05; DOF=89$)

On average, we expect the keyword to generate $\frac{N_{sales}}{90}$ sales each day.

So: $\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{90}\frac{(0 - \frac{N_{sales}}{90})^2}{\frac{N_{sales}}{90}}=N_{sales}$

Which yields:

$N_{sales}=P*N_{clicks}<\chi_{critical}^2$

$N_{clicks}<\frac{112.022}{P}$

Now, is it correct to say that if we had a number of clicks as big as or bigger than $\frac{112.022}{P}$, the keyword is actually a bad choice and should be paused?